# Completing relative URL to current webpage

Tags: javascript, uri

How do I write a javascript function that takes one string argument which is a relative url as if it were a relative path such as you might see in a Linux bash script and combines it with the url of the current webpage to find a resource relative to the current webpage.

Examples of relative url:

- file2.html
- ./file2.html
- ../foo/file2.html
- ././file2.html

Example results:

1. basic case

   - in webpage http://mysite.com/dir1/index.html
   - relative url foo.html
   - result http://mysite.com/dir1/foo.html
2. excess current directory dots (and local webpage)

   - in webpage file:///C:/Users/Me/dir1/dir2/page.html
   - relative url ././foo.html
   - result file:///C:/Users/Me/dir1/dir2/foo.html

     - or second preference file:///C:/Users/Me/dir1/dir2/././foo.html
3. parent directory (and some incidental excess dots, and another local webpage format)

   - in webpage file:///C|/Users/Me/dir1/dir2/anotherpage.html
   - relative url ./../././foo.html
   - result file:///C:/Users/Me/dir1/foo.html

     - or second preference file:///C:/Users/Me/dir1/dir2/./../././foo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working all-purpose solution:

```
function makePath(path, rel) {
    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + rel;
    var dirs = path.split("/");
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++) {
        if (dirs[i] == ".") continue;
        if (dirs[i] == "..") result.pop();
        else result.push(dirs[i]);
    }
    return result.join("/");
}
```

**​DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/h22SA/

Applying to the current page you should use:

```
makePath(location.href, "././foo.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [URI js library](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/)

Try `relativeTo`, `absoluteTo` functions there.

For example:

```
var uri = new URI("../../foo.html");
var newUri = uri.absoluteTo("file://C:/Users/Me/dir1/dir2/page.html"); 
// newUri == "file://C:/Users/Me/foo.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that accessing the `href` *property* of an anchor always gives you the absolute URL, you can simply create a temporary one and read the property:

```
function to_absolute_url(relative) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = relative;
    return a.href;
}
```

This of course works only if the URL you want to complete against is always the URL of the current page.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wNTUH/)